# How to idiomatically reload-or-start a unit in Chef?

Tags: chef-infra, systemd

I can't find how to idiomatically reload-or-restart a unit in Chef.

I have the problem that the `syslog-ng` unit reload doesn't have any effect (or it's broken, it's unclear), so I need to perform a `reload-or-restart`.

However, I can't find an obvious, idiomatic way of doing it:

- there is no `systemd_service` resource;
- the `systemd_unit` resource is not appropriate for non-managed units;
- if I use the `service` resource, with the `reload_command` and `provider` attributes set, and run the :reload action, the custom command seems to be ignored.

Therefore, I ended up using an `execute` resource. Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: Having such an `execute` resource "notified" to run when service configuration changes could be a good compromise.

Comment: The notification itself is not a problem - the problem is whether there is a more appopriate resource for performing this operation.